# How to pass a .ts variable to a .html page?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, chart.js

I have the following code in a typescript file:

```
"attributes.ts"

export class AttributesPage {
    chart: any[];

    constructor(
    //Assigning values to chartArray
    var chartArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
    //Should define the chart variable
    this.chart = chartArray

        })
    }
}
```

I want to assign the "chart" variable to a parameter in my .html file but am not able to pass it through and use it in the chart-here tag.

```
"attributes.html"

<ion-content>
    <ion-card-header>

            //Displays 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 
            {{this.chartArray}}

            //Displays 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
            {{this.chart}}

            //Undefined
            {{chart}}

        <ion-card-content>

                //When I try to assign the values of the variables to the [readings] parameter in <chart-here>
                     //"this.chartArray": undefined
                     //"this.chart": undefined
                     //"chart": undefined
                <chart-here [readings]= "chart"></chart-here>               

              </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card-header>
```

Alternatively, this works:

```
"attributes.html"

<ion-content>
    <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>

                <chart-here [readings]= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]></chart-here>               

              </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card-header>
```

Aswell as when I define the chart variable in my .ts page:

```
"attributes.ts"

export class AttributesPage {
    chart: any[] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

    constructor()
}
```

How can I define my chart variable or pass through this.chartArray/this.chart as variable to the "chart-here" tag?

Comment: and could you post the code that is at least compileable because yours is not?

Comment: @cale_b, made a clarification in the question. "this.chart" is able to pass into the .html page but I am not able to pass it into the "<chart-here>" tag (it goes through as undefined). The main issue that I have is that I am not able to pass through the "chart" variable from the attributes.ts page.

Comment: @smnbbrv, I rewrote the question in a way that should be easier to understand.